# How to configure an "initialise" method for Custom Processor

Tags: java, customization, mule, mule-studio

I have been working with Mule DevKit to create a custom message processor.

I have created the project with "mule-devkit-archetype-generic"  archetype.

It has given me the calss with annotations "@Module" and "@Processor"

I need to have some variables initialized when the object of this custom component is created. Those data will be used in my processor method.

But I couldn't find any help on how to create or annotate an Initialize method for these custom processors.

I have tried implementing "Initialisable"  and implementing the initialize method. But that gave error while compiling stating

```
The method name 'initialise' is not valid for a no-arg non-private method
```

Please suggest which way I can get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to implement an interface: using the `@PostConstruct` annotation on your initializing method should do the trick.

Comment: It worked. But I could see that the init method is called twice. Any idea why it happened so?

Comment: Also how can I access my MuleMessage and Payload inside my @Processor method.

Comment: Do you implement any interface that could trigger a second call to initialize? Also avoid naming the method 'initialise', it may mean something for DevKit. Can you ask your other questions in a new question? This has nothing to do with initialization, which is the subject of the current question.

Comment: I haven't implemented any other interface.  But I could see that there is a class generated during the build of this code. like "MyExtensionsModuleLifecycleAdapter.java"  which has call to my init method "myinit".